# VS2022 Viewing variable values in Data Tips - incorrect values displayed

Tags: windows, .net-core, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2022

I have a Net6.0 class library that has a method that fills a DTO class with values.
The DTO class:

```cs
       namespace AquaComm.Models;
        
        public class EvaluationLockDTO
        {
          public EvaluationType EvaluationType { get; set; }
          public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
          public bool IsExpired { get; set; }
          public bool LicenseFileAvailable { get; set; }
          public int Time { get; set; }
          public int TimeCurrent { get; set; }
        }
    and the method:
    
          public EvaluationLockDTO CheckEvaluationLock()
          {
            var evType = License.Status.Evaluation_Type;
            var lock_enabled = License.Status.Evaluation_Lock_Enabled;
            var time = License.Status.Evaluation_Time;
            var timeCurrent = License.Status.Evaluation_Time_Current;
        
            var evdto = new EvaluationLockDTO();
        
            evdto.EvaluationType = evType;
            if (timeCurrent > time)
              evdto.IsExpired = true;
            evdto.IsLocked = lock_enabled;
            evdto.Time = time;
            evdto.TimeCurrent = timeCurrent;
            evdto.LicenseFileAvailable = IsValidLicenseAvailable();
            return evdto;
          }
    
    The above class is injected into a Net6.0 console app and is accessed in:
    
          public AquaComm.Models.EvaluationLockDTO CheckEvaluationLock()
          {
            siLogger!.EnterMethod(Gurock.SmartInspect.Level.Debug, this, "CheckEvaluationLock");
            //var evdto = new EvaluationLockDTO();
            var evdto = netReactor.CheckEvaluationLock();
            siLogger!.LogObject("EvaluationLockDTO ", evdto);
        
        
            var myEvalLock = new MyEvalLock();
            myEvalLock.IsLocked = evdto.IsLocked;
            myEvalLock.IsExpired = evdto.IsExpired;
            myEvalLock.Time = evdto.Time;
            myEvalLock.TimeCurrent = evdto.TimeCurrent;
            myEvalLock.LicenseFileAvailable = evdto.LicenseFileAvailable;
        
        
        
            siLogger!.LeaveMethod(Gurock.SmartInspect.Level.Debug, this, "CheckEvaluationLock");
            siLogger!.LogObject("MyEvalLock ", myEvalLock);
            return evdto;
          }
```

Running the application in Debug mode reveals the following Data tips:

[image: evdto]

and:

[image: myEvalLock]

The first screen capture shows the DTO `evdto` and the second is a copy of the DTO class named `myEvalLock` which belongs to the console application. The `myEvalLock` class is solely populated by the contents of the `evdto` class.

Why is the Data Tip for the `evdto` not displaying the real/actual values that are contained in the class?

Comment: The question is confusing, what do you expect the tooltips to contain? What is `MyEvalLock`? Please provide a [mre] or we can't really help you.

Comment: @DavidG myEvalLock contained in the console namespace is a clone of the evtdo class contained in the DI class library. If you look at the code partially hidden by the Data Tip for myEvalLock you will see that myEvalLock is populated by the actual real values contained in evtdo. That means the values displayed in the Data Tip for evdto are incorrect.